# ffmpeg ios: Getting frame to UIImage, failing at YUV420 to RGB conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, uiimage

I'm trying to extract a thumbnail from a movie file using ffmpeg. I found [iFrameExtractor](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor) and tried using its code as the base for what I'm doing. There seems to be an option at compiling FFMPEG that I'm missing, because this part of the code is generating...

```
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, 
                                     pCodecCtx->height,
                                     pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                     outputWidth, 
                                     outputHeight,
                                     PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                     sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This error:

```
[swscaler @ 0x7ffb6a06d600] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
```

If you look at [libswscale/yuv2rgb.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/yuv2rgb_8c_source.html), on line 612, it says that operation is only supported on PPC and x86.

I'm at a loss now. Is there an option when compiling it that includes support for this? Is there any way to convert it some other way?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Recompiled ffmpeg from a fresh script and it works now.

Comment: What's the script ? Thanks

Comment: This one: https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Although I'm now using the cocoapod of it: https://cocoapods.org/pods/FFmpeg

Comment: For anyone googling this old question, it's worth noting that if you're on an iPhone, FFmpeg will do that conversion BUT not using the GPU, it will do it on the CPU.  So you will get a confusing warning, which seems to suggest  it has failed, but, it is only a warning!!!!!!!!!  It works perfectly.